# Build a matrix for a multi regression model with qualitative data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, linear-regression

I'm trying to build a multi regression model with qualitative data.

In order to do that I need to build a new data frame that creates a new data frame with columns based on the unique values and marks 1 if the index had that value.

Example:

```
d = {'City': ['Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon','Tokyo','Madrid','Lisbon','Madrid','London','Tokyo','London','Tokyo'], 
     'Card': ['Visa','Visa','Visa','Master Card','Bitcoin','Master Card','Bitcoin','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Bitcoin'],
     'Client Number':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
     }

d = pd.DataFrame(data=d).set_index('Client Number')
```

And get a result equal to this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `get_dummies`

```
df = pd.get_dummies(d,prefix='', prefix_sep='')
Out[202]: 
               Lisbon  London  Madrid  Tokyo  Bitcoin  Master Card  Visa
Client Number                                                           
1                   0       0       0      1        0            0     1
2                   0       0       0      1        0            0     1
3                   1       0       0      0        0            0     1
4                   0       0       0      1        0            1     0
5                   0       0       1      0        1            0     0
6                   1       0       0      0        0            1     0
7                   0       0       1      0        1            0     0
8                   0       1       0      0        0            0     1
9                   0       0       0      1        0            1     0
10                  0       1       0      0        0            0     1
11                  0       0       0      1        1            0     0
```